# How to connect multiple peers in multiple machines in hyperledger-fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have followed the hyperledger fabric docs and installed the fabric samples but now i want to connect one more peer into the network using a different machine

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this via docker swarm mode. Your primary machine (currently having the network) will initiate swarm mode. The other machine will join it as manager node. Then you will create a network on the top of the swarm mode. All the PCs that are connected to your swarm will share the network and will enable all the containers to communicate with each other effectively. You will follow the complete tutorial at

[Hyperledger Fabric on Multiple Hosts](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f)